# How to play Buzzer using Arduino Matlab

Tags: matlab, arduino

as i mentioned above how to play a tone using arduino+buzzer ? 
in this matlab help article [playTone() Play tone on piezo speaker using digital pin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ref/playtone.html) there is playTone function.but in my packages i dont have those functions. is there any fubction to play buzzer using matlab?[like Tone() function in arduino ide]

Comment: I don't understand your problem, have you followed those steps : [Documentation](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ug/intro.html) ?

Comment: @obchardon yup i followed it and install the same package,but there is no command called playTone in that package,when i try that command i get "Undefined function 'playTone' for input arguments of type 'arduino'"